# cell borders not copied with paste special

Tags: excel, vbscript

Total newbie to VB Scripting. 
My question is 2 part:
I need to copy a 450 column header from one excel sheet to another excel sheet with data. 
The header has table borders and is formatted. I looked up some examples online and put together this script which does the copy.

However, the cell borders are not being copied. Just the text - so the header formatting is not carried over.

below is my code.

is this not the correct way to paste the borders as well?

Once copied with borders, if I were to copy this sheet to another sheet, will the cell borders and formatting be carried over as well?

```
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objExcel.Visible = True

      Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("header.xlsx")
      Set wksSource = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("IS3.xlsx")
      Set wksDest = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("TD")

       Set objRange = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:IZ3").Copy
       wksDest.Range("A1:IZ3").PasteSpecial  objRange
       objWorkbook1.Save
       objWorkbook1.Close

       objWorkbook2.Save
       objWorkbook2.Close

       objExcel.Quit
       Set objExcel = Nothing
       Set wksSource = Nothing
       Set wksDest = Nothing
```

Comment: might be easier to copy the whole sheet and remove the extra ranges if needed. If the header cells stay fixed at the top when you scroll down, those are probably not borders but Freeze panes https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paste special has no directive.  You'll need to hit it twice.  Once for the formats, and once for the values.

```
wksDest.Range("A1:IZ3").PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteFormats objRange
wksDest.Range("A1:IZ3").PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValues objRange
```

Comment: Using vbscript you won't be able to use the vba constants. Need to find out the actual value for xlPasteFormats and xlPasteValues and use those